# Allowing oracle db login only to specific application?

Tags: oracle, security, authentication, single-sign-on

We want to allow DB access (Oracle) to our users only through our own application - let's call it "ourTool.exe", installed locally on the users computers. Currently, the users must provide username/password whenever they start "ourTool". The provided password password gets decrypted and we use username/decrypted-password to finally log in to the Oracle DB. This approach prevents the users from directly accessing our DB using third party tools (SQLplus, Excel, Access, ...) and everything in the DB is guaranteed to have been entered/edited using "ourTool".

Now, one of our clients wants to allow its users "single sign-on" (with SmartCards/Oracle PKI). With this, the user will be able connect to our DB without providing any password every time they start "ourTool". But the same will be true for the potentially dangerous tools like SQLplus, Excel, Access, etc.

Is there a way to prevent this? How can we make sure that every record in our DB is only created/edited/deleted using "ourTool" in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's your application and you have control of the source, you can use either password protected database roles or Secure Application Roles that are enabled from ourTool.exe.  (see http://www.oracle.com/technology/obe/obe10gdb/security/approles/approles.htm ).

For example, with a password-protected database role, the initial connection would be with only the CREATE SESSION privilege, and then ourTool.exe would issue the SET ROLE with password known only to you.  Any other application doesn't  have the information to set the role.  Obviously, the privileges are granted only to the role and not directly to the user in this configuration.

Comment: Be careful about embedding the PW in the source - there are many tools to allow you to see the embedded ASCII strings in an executable.

Comment: good point - yes, you do have to come up with some way of obfuscating the string in the .exe

Comment: Unless you are securing the network traffic, they could still pick up the text being passed from the PC to the database. I think SQL*net encryption is part of one of the extra cost options for Enterprise edition.

Comment: Yes, SQL*Net encryption is still part of the extra cost Advanced Security Option.  Both you and DCookie have valid points for the fringe case of someone determined to connect to the database and gain privileges, but I believe the spirit of the original question was how to deal with the  average desktop user who has SQL*Plus or ODBC connectivity.  I hope Oracle eventually rolls the Adv. Sec. option into the Enterprise Edition - it seems wrong to pay extra for securing a company's product.

Comment: We are going to use the ideas presented here, and we might also include a query on v$session (see answer of Quassnoi). 
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

By default, `OCI` transmits the calling application `EXE` name and you can access it by querying `v$session`:

```
SELECT  program
FROM    V$SESSION
```

, which you can do in an `AFTER LOGON` trigger.

But this can be easily overriden and should not be relied upon.

Answer (score 1):

I renamed my sqlplus.exe to myTool.exe and after making a connection with myTool.exe

```
SELECT  program
FROM    V$SESSION
where username = 'SYSTEM';
```

Returns: 
myTool.exe

So be aware, as Quassnoi said: although usable in some circumstances it's certainly not bullit proof.