# How to authorize a user/application combination in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, authentication, active-directory, kerberos

I'd like to authorize the user/application combination, not only the user.

The scenario is that we've built an app that guides the user to safe updates of some data.

If the same user installs PL/SQL Dev, Toad, or any other Oracle management tool, she can edit the data in ways that the app prohibits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vincent's answer is good (and he also makes a good point in his comment about spoofing the executable).

For a more programmatic method (no mid tier), see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007308/allowing-oracle-db-login-only-to-specific-application/1007445#1007445) to a similar question.  It basically involves coding an ALTER SESSION into your application that enables a role.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a proxy user to restrict access to the database. Your users would only be able to connect (authentication) and activate a role (authorization) through the middle-tier account. They would not need to know their DB password. They can be authenticated externally (with AD for example).

See [this thread on AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:21575905259251) and [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/admnauth.htm#sthref1275) for further reading.

Answer (score 0):

The v$session view contains a column 'program'. This contains the name of the connected application. You may be able to use this information.

To determine the sessions ID use this:

select
   sys_context('USERENV','SID')
from dual;

Comment: Unfortunately the program column can easily be spoofed (`cp sqlplus your_application_name`), you should not rely on it for security.

Comment: Thanks, for pointing this out and I'm glad for showing the way not to to this.